# Não inserir zeros à esquerda de um número

Tags: javascript

Tenho n inputs, que são criadas dinamicamente. O que acontece, é que elas não podem aceitar zeros à esquerda nas seguintes ocasiões:

0.24 -> O sistema aceita

00.24 -> O sistema remove automaticamente o zero à esquerda ficando 0.24

034.55 -> O sistema remove automaticamente o zero à esquerda ficando 34.55

Ou seja, o zero à esquerda só é possível quando existe encostado à esquerda do ponto.

Para fazer para todas as inputs dinamicamente, estou a iniciar com a seguinte função:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keypress(function(e) {
        // Verificar os zero à esquerda     

        }
    });
});
```

É possível aqui, verificar estas condições do zero à esquerda? Ou então usando o onchage?

Comment: Possível é, basta ver se a informação começa com zero e descartar a tecla, mas qual o problema de fato que está tentando resolver? Qual seria o problema de deixar o zero à esquerda e tratar na aplicação assim que o dado for enviado? Desse jeito vc vai ter que tratar situações como copiar e colar, deletar o ponto e dois zeros "encostarem" e mais um monte de condições. Me parece um [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/70).

Comment: @Bacco copiar colar não me interessa, só quero limitar quando o utilizador está a escrever. O problema é que o cliente quer esta validação em tempo real e não estou a conseguir resolver..

Comment: Então, se ele colar um número com 000.23 e enviar, tudo bem? Seu cliente está com um baita problema XY.

Comment: @Bacco sim, envia...Ele ao colar o número 000.23, ele ao grava fica apenas com 0.23. Mas o problema é ao escrever, é um cliente que não tem nada onde criticar, então critica aqui.

Comment: @Bacco talvez a melhor opção seja com o onchage em cada input, não?

Comment: Teria que cobrir o input, o change e mesmo assim tem browser que não passa os eventos corretamente. Se for importante demais, a solução pode ser um timer olhando o valor e ajustando. Enquanto começar com dois zeros, troca pra um. Mas aí tem outra coisa pra resolver: tem que subtrair uma posição do cursor a cada troca, senão a digitação fica meio "esquisita".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segue um exemplo usando `setInterval`.

Foi feito desta forma para trabalhar diretamente no valor, independente da maneira com que os dados foram entrados.

Teste aqui:

```js
var l = document.getElementsByClassName( 'zeros' );
setInterval( function(){
  for ( var i = 0; i < l.length; i++ ) {
    while( l[i].value.length > 1 && l[i].value.substring( 0, 1 ) == '0' && l[i].value.substring( 0, 2 ) != '0.' ) {
      var s = l[i].selectionStart;
      l[i].value = l[i].value.substring( 1 );
      l[i].selectionEnd = l[i].selectionStart = s - 1;
    }
  }
}, 75);
```

```html
<input class="zeros" type="text"><br>
<input class="zeros" type="text"><br>
<input class="zeros" type="text"><br>
```

Características:

- Funciona ao digitar, copiar e colar e deletar caracteres;
- funciona mesmo se o texto for mudado por JS, pois é baseado no conteúdo;
- atualiza a posição do cursor nos *browsers* modernos (útil no caso de a alteração ser causada por um backspace ou deleção de caractere intermediário);
- localiza os campos pela classe, facilitando a implementação.

Comment: ele aqui, deixa me inserir 023.32 por exemplo. copiar colar perfeito!

Comment: Ok, obrigado! fico aguardar então.

Comment: @Bacco só consegui analisar agora a resposta actualizada. Ficou perfeito! obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Essa expressão regular substitui os caracteres excedentes. No seu caso, os zeros a esquerda.

```
str = '0000.00';
str = str.replace(/^0+(?!\.|$)/, '');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Pode por favor verificar se está correcto, a mim imprime igual https://jsfiddle.net/xxoLzrh6/

Comment: faltou apenas atribuir ao str...