# Regex - validação de preços para MySQL decimal(12,2)

Tags: regex

Eu tenho um fomulário onde existe um campo **preço** que será preenchido pelo usuário.
O objetivo é aceitar algumas entradas e bloquear outras (validação).
O valor será guardado numa base de dados MySQL, num campo do tipo **decimal(12,2)**. Isso quer dizer que esse campo aceitará um valor total de 12 algarismos, sendo 2 decimais.
Ex1: 1111111111 será guardado no MySql como 1111111111.00. Ou seja, mesmo que o usuário não entre os centavos, a precisão de .00 será guardada. 
Ex2: 1234567890.00 é um valor válido enquanto 12345678901.00 não é pois ultrapassou 12 algarismos. 
Ex3:.23 é um valor válido pois MySql transforma em 0.23 dentro da tabela. Mas "." (só o ponto) não é válido, enquanto que .0 é válido (será guardado como 0.00).

Entáo as regras são as seguintes:

1. Aceitar um valor onde exista somente algarismos ou algarismos e ".".
2. Não aceita somente ".".
3. Se houver "." só pode existir dois algarismos no máximo depois dele.
4. Antes do "." só poderá existir no máximo 10 algarismos.
5. Se não houver "." só poderá existir no máximo 10 algarismos.

Para esse filtro eu tenho a seguinte regex: 
`^\d{0,8}?(\.)?(\d{1,2})?$` [link](https://regex101.com/r/sB7qT6/2)

Ela está funcionando para todos os cenários exceto para estes:

1. Qundo não tem "." ele aceita até 12 algarismos. Assim 12345678901 não deveria aceitar pois tem 11 algarismos.
2. O ponto sozinho está sendo aceito mas não deveria "."

No mais tudo parece ok.
Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

---

NOTA:

Embora não seja importante para essa pergunta, vou postar a função javascript que usa o parâmetro regex. Ela está funcionando corretamente. Adiciona um [tooltip de bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp) quando o usuário insere algo não esperado pelo padrão regex

```
$('#txt_preco').bind({             

             keyup:function(){

                   var objectEvent=$(this);
                   var ck_input = /^\d+$/;
                   var input = $.trim(objectEvent.val());
                   var validationTest =ck_input.test(input);                 

                   //QTY field Validation --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   if(!validationTest||input==='0'){//If not match ck_input
                         //alert("algo errado"+input);

                                 objectEvent.val('');//Clear input field
                                 $(this).attr('data-original-title','Oops! Only numbers 1-9 are allowed');
                                 $(this).tooltip('show');
                                 setTimeout( function(){ 
                                       objectEvent.tooltip('hide');
                                       objectEvent.removeAttr('title');
                                       objectEvent.removeAttr('data-original-title'); 
                                   }  , 2500 ); //Wait 2,5 seconds                                                      


                   }
                   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   else{//If validation match ck_input


                         objectEvent.tooltip('hide');
                                            objectEvent.removeAttr('title');
                                            objectEvent.removeAttr('data-original-title');   

                   }//End of else if(!validationTest||input==='0'){
             }//Fim keyUp
    });//End of $('.txt_qty').bind({
```

Comment: Só uma observação: normalmente o tratamento de dados no formulário deve ser feito para preservar a UX, para o usuário fazer o preenchimento de maneira convencional. Converter o formato para o do MySQL deveria ser responsabilidade do software (ou seja, do programador, e não do usuário) na hora do insert. Não que você não possa usar RegEx para isto, mas me parece ter uma mistura de dois conceitos complelamente diferentes na pergunta (entrada de dados vs. formato para armazenagem). A região do software usa `.` como separador de decimais? No Brasil, por exemplo, o separador correto é `,`.

Comment: Correto. Essse é um campo optativo, mas se for preenchido será tratado. Existe uma função em javascript (que eu não postei aqui) que vai informar ao usuário o modelo correto se ele cometer algum erro. através de um tooltip. E quanto ao separador, eu estou desenvolvendo algo para um cliente de fora do brasil. A minha abordagem é filtrar ao máximo com REGEX para diminuir as linhas de código (sem prejuízo a UX)

Comment: Talvez seja legal mencionar isso na pergunta, pois se vai validar pelo html não dá pra ter muita liberdade, mas se for para usar no JS, pode ter coisa melhor do que só o RegEx para validar o campo. Aliás, em JS dá até pra fazer o campo reagir ao se digitar nele.

Comment: esse aqui é um exemplo de como mudar os dados no momento da digitação, é para tirar zeros à esquerda, menos quando tem ponto. Ele poderia ser adaptado para fazer algo em relação a todos os caracteres inválidos, por exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118775/70

Comment: Posso postar mas a função em si não é o problema. Ela simplesmente retorna verdadeiro ou falso baseado no seu criterio de pesquisa. E sim, a resposta de javascript ao digitar nele é um tooltip.

Comment: Só comentei da função, pois muitas vezes tem como por parte das condições com lógica de strings, em vez de usar RegEx, mas é claro que você tem que avaliar o que é melhor.

Comment: Veja se isto resolve: `^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,2})?` - teste: http://www.regexr.com/3deuh

Comment: O seu padrão {0,8} não está pegando 10 dígitos antes do ponto. Mas alterando para {0,10} resolve. A única coisa que fica faltande é o match de dígitoscom um ponto. https://regex101.com/r/sB7qT6/3

Comment: como "Faltando"? Ele pega, a cor diferente é só por causa dos parênteses, por ser um grupo de captura.

Comment: veja a última linha do link que eu mandei. https://regex101.com/r/sB7qT6/3  ele deveria pegar o ponto tbm

Answer (score 0):

Ok, aqui está o padrão procurado.
Vou comprtihar para quem tiver interesse.

```
^(?!\.$)\d{0,10}(?:\.(?:\d\d?)?)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/yX1kF6/4

E aqui está a função completa para validar esse tipo de entrada:

```
$('#txt_preco').bind({             

             keyup:function(){

                   var objectEvent=$(this);
                   var ck_input = /^(?!\.$)\d{0,10}(?:\.(?:\d\d?)?)?$/;
                   var input = $.trim(objectEvent.val());
                   var validationTest =ck_input.test(input);                 

                   //QTY field Validation --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   if(!validationTest||input==='0'){//If not match ck_input
                         //alert("algo errado"+input);

                                 objectEvent.val('');//Clear input field
                                 $(this).attr('data-original-title','Oops! Only numbers 1-9 are allowed');
                                 $(this).tooltip('show');
                                 setTimeout( function(){ 
                                       objectEvent.tooltip('hide');
                                       objectEvent.removeAttr('title');
                                       objectEvent.removeAttr('data-original-title'); 
                                   }  , 2500 ); //Wait 2,5 seconds                                                      


                   }
                   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   else{//If validation match ck_input


                         objectEvent.tooltip('hide');
                                            objectEvent.removeAttr('title');
                                            objectEvent.removeAttr('data-original-title');   

                   }//End of else if(!validationTest||input==='0'){
             }//Fim keyUp
    });//End of $('.txt_qty').bind({
```